# Read Title from Excel files Metadata

Tags: vba, excel

Would anyone know why I get "Object does not support this property or method" with my code. It works fine until I add the line:

```
Cells(i + ROW_FIRST - 1, 4) = objFile.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Title")
```

Full code:

```
Option Explicit
'the first row with data
Const ROW_FIRST As Integer = 5

'This is an event handler. It exectues when the user
'presses the run button
Private Sub btnGet_Click()
'determines if the user selects a directory
'from the folder dialog
Dim intResult As Integer
'the path selected by the user from the
'folder dialog
Dim strPath As String
'Filesystem object
Dim objFSO As Object
'the current number of rows
Dim intCountRows As Integer
Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker).Title = _
"Select a Path"
'the dialog is displayed to the user
intResult = Application.FileDialog( _
msoFileDialogFolderPicker).Show
'checks if user has cancled the dialog
If intResult <> 0 Then
    strPath = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker _
    ).SelectedItems(1)
    'Create an instance of the FileSystemObject
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    'loops through each file in the directory and prints their
    'names and path
    intCountRows = GetAllFiles(strPath, ROW_FIRST, objFSO)
    'loops through all the files and folder in the input path
    Call GetAllFolders(strPath, objFSO, intCountRows)
End If
End Sub
'''
'This function prints the name and path of all the files
'in the directory strPath
'strPath: The path to get the list of files from
'intRow: The current row to start printing the file names
'in
'objFSO: A Scripting.FileSystem object.
Private Function GetAllFiles(ByVal strPath As String, _
ByVal intRow As Integer, ByRef objFSO As Object) As Integer
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile As Object
Dim i As Integer
i = intRow - ROW_FIRST + 1
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strPath)
For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        'print file name
        Cells(i + ROW_FIRST - 1, 1) = objFile.Name
        'print file path
        Cells(i + ROW_FIRST - 1, 2) = objFile.Path
        Cells(i + ROW_FIRST - 1, 3) = objFile.Size
        Cells(i + ROW_FIRST - 1, 4) = objFile.LastModifiedDate
        Cells(i + ROW_FIRST - 1, 4) = objFile.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Title")
        i = i + 1
Next objFile
GetAllFiles = i + ROW_FIRST - 1
End Function

'''
'This function loops through all the folders in the
'input path. It makes a call to the GetAllFiles
'function. It also makes a  recursive call to itself
'strFolder: The folder to loop through
'objFSO: A Scripting.FileSystem object
'intRow: The current row to print the file data on
Private Sub GetAllFolders(ByVal strFolder As String, _
    ByRef objFSO As Object, ByRef intRow As Integer)
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objSubFolder As Object

'Get the folder object
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strFolder)
'loops through each file in the directory and
'prints their names and path
For Each objSubFolder In objFolder.subfolders
    intRow = GetAllFiles(objSubFolder.Path, _
        intRow, objFSO)
    'recursive call to to itsself
    Call GetAllFolders(objSubFolder.Path, _
        objFSO, intRow)
Next objSubFolder
End Sub
```

Comment: You are accessing a scripting file, not an excel object.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242698(v=vs.60).aspx

Answer (score -1):

Something like this

```
Public Function GET_EXCEL_TITLE(strPath As String, strFileName As String) As String

Dim shlShell As Shell32.IShellDispatch5
Dim fldFolder As Shell32.Folder3

If FILE_EXISTS(strPath & "\" & strFileName) Then

    Set shlShell = New Shell32.Shell
    Set fldFolder = shlShell.Namespace(strPath & "\")


    With fldFolder
        GET_EXCEL_TITLE = .GetDetailsOf(.Items.Item(strFileName), 21)
    End With

Else

    GET_EXCEL_TITLE = "File not found"

End If

If Not shlShell Is Nothing Then Set shlShell = Nothing
If Not fldFolder Is Nothing Then Set fldFolder = Nothing

End Function
```